# How to multiply a class with local variables with random values?

Tags: java, android

I have this class called "Enemy". Inside of it there is a bitmap and some methods that animate the movement of this bitmap.

So what I want to do is to multiply this class X times. I do that with a "for" loop and an array, but what I've discovered is that the variables inside the class end up being all the same, despite the fact that their values are random (Math.random()).

This works if I declare the variables outside the class, but that's not what I want, because I want the class to be independent. I want the same class, multiplied by X times, moving independently one from the other.

Thanks very much.

```
public class Enemy {

    float q,w,e,r = 0;
    public void execute(){

        draw();
        move();
    }

    public void draw(){
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.base);

        if(q == 0 && w == 0 || q > e-5 && q < e+5 || w > e-5 && w < e+5){
            e = 100 + (float) (Math.random()*200);
            r = 100 + (float) (Math.random()*200);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, q, w, null);

    }

    public void move () {

        if(q<e && w<r) {
        new Thread(); {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                EplusPlus();
        }}}

        if(q<e && w>r) { 
        new Thread(); {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                EplusMinus(); 

        }}}

        if(q>e && w<r) {
        new Thread(); {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                EminusPlus();
        }}}

        if(q>e && w>r) {
        new Thread(); {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                EminusMinus();
        }}}
```

}

I call the class like this:

```
public void run() {
        while(isRunning) {
            if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

                canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawRGB(30, 30, 200);

                Enemy[] enemy = new Enemy[3];
                for(int i = 0; i<enemy.length; i++){
                enemy[i].execute();
                }



            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }           
    }
```

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing your code, but it sound like your class has static variables when what you need are non-static variable.

Comment: How random is random? You could throw more math in it and use a time function, which makes it different for every instance.

Comment: I've got my variables declared like this float q,w,e,r = Math.random()*100;. How do I make them non-static?

Comment: Please add the lines of code, where you instantiate Enemy and setup variables. For me it sounds like you generate random numbers from the same seed for each of your Enemies. But we'll see that, if you post the responsive code snippets.

Comment: WHERE is the constructor call for Enemy? so far i can only see you creating the array, but it stays an emtpty array. So i wonder, how you don't get a nullpointerexception in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use the special Random class. Instead `Math.random()`, use [`Ramdom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class and do seeding.

`Random generater = new Random(seed);
double random=generater.nextDouble();`